# todos is not defined error in my vuex store mutation

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

hoping you can help

I am doing an axios post to a firebase backend through a vuex module action  but when i try and push my results to sync the store I get the following error

```
todos is not defined
```

I have checked everything right upto knowing my todo does contain the object I want to add to the array in my mutation but no idea why todos would be undefined?

In my store I have

```
import axios from "axios";

// ***  STATE  ***
export const state = () => ({
  todos: []
})

// ***  MUTATIONS  ***
export const mutations = {

  // add new todo to todos array
  add(state, todo ) {
    state.todos.push({todo})
    // this is where my error is todos is not defined
  },

export const actions = {

  addPost(context, todo) {
    const createdPost = {
      ...todo
    }
    axios.post("http", createdPost)
    .then(result => {
       context.commit('add', {...createdPost, id: result.data.name})
       console.log(createdPost)  // this returns the object I expect to get from firebase with the added ID

    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
  },
}
export const getters = {
  todos(state) {
    return state.todos
  }
}
```

I should add I am converting my axios object to an array when i initially get the data with the following action

```
loadData ({ commit, context }) {
    return axios.get('http')
    .then(res => {
      const converttodo = []
      for (const key in res.data) {
        converttodo.push({ ...res.data[key], id: key })
      }
      // console.log(converttodos)
      commit('setTodos', converttodo)
    })
    //.catch(e => context.error(e));
  },
```

this behaves as expected.

Many Thanks

Comment: you are passing an object as a payload to the add mutation. So just do `state.todos.push(todo)` not `state.todos.push({todo})`.

Comment: ahhhh, been staring at it for too long and didnt spot that, thanks